# How to get a specific element from a div that is the parent of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm having a few issues while trying to get the content of specific elements based on the place where the button was clicked.

The divs looks like this:

```
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img class='card-img-top' src="" alt='Card image cap'>
                        <div class='card-body text-center'>
                            <p class='card-text text-center' style='color: black'> Model</p>
                            <ul class='list-group list-group-flush'>
                                <li class='list-group-item'>
                                    <div class='row'>
                                        <div class='col-md-6'>
                                            <i class='material-icons'>&#xe227;</i><span> Price </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='col-md-6'>
                                            <i class='material-icons'>&#xe0c8;</i><span>City1</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger saveAd">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <img class='card-img-top' src="" alt='Card image cap'>
                            <div class='card-body text-center'>
                                <p class='card-text text-center' style='color: black'> Model</p>
                                <ul class='list-group list-group-flush'>
                                    <li class='list-group-item'>
                                        <div class='row'>
                                            <div class='col-md-6'>
                                                <i class='material-icons'>&#xe227;</i><span> Price </span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class='col-md-6'>
                                                <i class='material-icons'>&#xe0c8;</i><span>City2</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger saveAd">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

If someone clicks on the second button how can i get the content of the span element which has the text City2?
I've tried something like this:

```
       $('.btn.btn-danger.saveAd').on('click', function () {
            console.log("Button pressed!");
            console.log($(this).find('span-size').text());
        });
```

Of course it's not working..how should i do it?

Comment: What logic are you using to select the proper span? You have  two of them in the given example that fall under the parent div of the button.

Comment: `span-size` is not a valid selector.  Also, there are no children of the button so `find()` is not going to find anything.

Comment: Based on where is the button placed i need to get the city , price and model. If the first button is clicked i need to retrieve the values from the first div and so on

Comment: `$(this).closest('.card').find(whateverOtherThingInTheCardYouNeed)`  `find()` goes down the DOM Tree.  `closest()` goes up.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if i understood everything.

Do you want to display the last span text when the submit button is clicked, right ?
So, do this:

```
$('.btn.btn-danger.saveAd').on('click', function () {
    var lastSpanElement = $(this).closest('div').find('span:eq(1)');

    alert(lastSpanElement.text());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thiagotrss/v8c70m1k/2/

Comment: If you are just going to re-wrap an element with `$()`, don't break it out with `[]`.  Use `eq(#)` instead.

Comment: Not the [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq) I meant, but that one would work as well

Answer (score 1):

Give a class to the span with text `City2`,for example `span-size`. And use this class in the click event of the button

```
$('.btn.btn-danger.saveAd').on('click',   
function () { 
 console.log($(this).closest('.card-body').find('.span-size').text());

});`
```

The `closest('.card-body')` method in above code goes to the first ancestor of the button, with class `card-body` and searches it for a span with class `span-size`